# Redux Toolkit + Redux sagas

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I refactoring the store in my project with redux toolkit and we use also redux sagas;
So I have a slice with an action:

```
 createTask: (state: myTypeState, action:PayloadAction<myTypeState>) => {
      state.createTaskStatus = status.fetching
    },
```

In my sagas I connect the two part like that:

```
takeLatest(createTask().type, mySagaFunction),
```

In my component I use it like that with 3 parameters, needed for my saga:

```
dispatch(createTask({
        name,
        pictureFile: picture,
        jobstation,
      }))
```

But in my action I didn't use the second parameters and so I have an eslint warning:

`Unused parameter action``

How can I fix that warning ?

ps: I have also try to connect toolkit and sagas like that:

```
export const createTaskAction = createAction(types.CREATE_TASK)
```

and

```
 takeLatest(CREATE_TASK, createTask),
```

With that, i need to dispatch this createTaskAction and the goal is to remove as much code as possible ^^
what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Can't you just remove the second param from createTask if you are not using it?

Comment: @MartinKadlec thx for your response, sorry I have edited my question.
Nope because I need to pass parameters for my saga...

Answer (score 0):

This will work without `Unused parameter action`:

```js
createTask: (state: myTypeState) => {
  state.createTaskStatus = status.fetching
},
```